# params in actionIndex giving Error 500, Undefined variable: id in YII

Tags: php, yii

I have added the code below in my actionView and actionIndex. The code works  code works fine when used in actionView, but throws me  Error 500,  Undefined variable: id, when used on actionIndex. Why variable id is undefined only on actionIndex?

actionView ...

```
public function actionView($id)  
{  

            $textDataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Text', array(  
        'criteria'=>array(  
            'condition'=>'articles_id=:articlesId',  
            'params'=>array(':articlesId'=>$this->loadModel($id)->id),  
        ),  
        'pagination'=>array(  
            'pageSize'=>1,  
        ),  
     ));  
    $this->render('view',array(  
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),  
                    'textDataProvider'=>$textDataProvider,  

    ));  
}
```

the same code, with only a small change for actionIndex ...

```
public function actionIndex()
{       

        //get text information
        $textDataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Text', array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>'articles_id=:articlesId',
                             'params'=>array(':articlesId'=>$this->loadModel($id)->id),
                            'offset'=>'0',
                            'limit' => '1',


        ),
        ));
        //get criteria
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        //$criteria->condition = 'country = :country';
        //$criteria->params = array (':country'=> $_GET['country']);
        $criteria->order = 'create_time desc';

        //get count
        $count = Articles::model()->count($criteria);

        //pagination
        $pages = new CPagination($count);
        $pages->setPageSize(10);
        $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

        //result to show on page
        $result = Articles::model()->findAll($criteria);
        $dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($result);



        $this->render('index', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'pages' => $pages,
        'textDataProvider'=>$textDataProvider,
        ));


   }
```

I've maded a change to the actionIndex trying to get the id, as pointed out below. But I still can get the id.

actionIndex ...

public function actionIndex()
    {

```
    //get criteria
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    //$criteria->condition = 'country = :country';
    //$criteria->params = array (':country'=> $_GET['country']);
    $criteria->order = 'create_time desc';

    //get count
    $count = Articles::model()->count($criteria);

    //pagination
    $pages = new CPagination($count);
    $pages->setPageSize(10);
    $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

    //result to show on page
    $result = Articles::model()->findAll($criteria);
    $dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($result);


    //$arr = array();
    foreach($result as $id)
    {
      $text_id = $id->id;
    }

     //get text information
    $criteria2=new CDbCriteria(array(                    
                            'order'=>'id desc',

                            'condition'=>'articles_id='.$text_id,

                    ));

    $textProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Text', array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria2,
));  
    $this->render('index', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'pages' => $pages,
    'textProvider'=>$textProvider,
    ));
   }
```

Comment: Define your function as  actionView($id=null) then try it

Comment: Thanks for your message @YatinMistry, but the problem is with actionIndex

Comment: Sorry i have missed wrong function name just try function as actionIndex($id=null)

Comment: Thanks again @YatinMistry. That gives an error Error 404

The requested page does not exist. I'm having problems with this id, but I'll get there.

Comment: Hey @YatinMistry, can you please have a look at question again? I have added a new piece of could, still can't get the id. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's obvious, you are using `$id` without defining it! In `actionView`, you have `$id` as parameter, but in `actionIndex` you don't have it. So `'params'=>array(':articlesId'=>$this->loadModel($id)` causes **Undefined variable** error. 
For solving this problem, you must pass `$id` to your `actionIndex` too.

Comment: It took me a while to see that. the $id referred in actionView loads the model, loadModel ($id). I using "with" in the $dataProvider array. Thanks for pointing it out @hamed

Comment: Do you know how to get the id @hamed? Please see my edit question with the new actionIndex